# I have to send a image email in lotus script how to do that?

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I created one form with a field richtextitem lite and image is kept in that when i click the action send mail.. a mail should be sent to tne id " abc" with image in it
Any one please provide me the code for developing it

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is documented in the designer help file. [Setting up automatic mailing](http://www-12.lotus.com/ldd/doc/domino_notes/6.5.1/help65_designer.nsf/f4b82fbb75e942a6852566ac0037f284/7ff9387e4081dc5e85256e000049377f?OpenDocument) or open this Db: Help\help85_designer.nsf

Depending on the requirements you have 3 options:
- system action
- formula
- LotusScript

Comment: If this answer answered your question:"When you have decided which answer is the most helpful to you, mark it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check box outline to the left of the answer. This lets other people know that you have received a good answer to your question. Doing this is helpful because it shows other people that you’re getting value from the community. (If you don’t do this, people will often politely ask you to go back and accept answers for more of your questions!)"